# React Next.js not calling useEffect hook in production app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering

I have a decently large Next.js/React application. A few days ago, some pages which worked flawlessly before, started behaving weirdly - more specifically, some Axios requests inside of a `useEffect` hook stopped being sent at all.

**More details:**

This is the file which is causing the bugs:

```
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);

  useEffect(async () => {
    const { data: result } = await axiosApp.get("/auth-status"); // axiosApp = same thing as axios
    setAuth(result);
  }, []);

  return !auth ? (
    <div className="pretend-this-is-a-progress-bar"></div>
  ) : (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={[auth, setAuth]}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

As you can see I'm using react context here for the authentication in my app. This component here is located in the `_app.js` file, and the different next.js pages are passed as children of the `<ContextProvider/>`.

As you can also see, this file sends a request to `auth-staus` in it's `useEffect` hook, which tells the app whether the user is logged in or not. The problem is, **and I found this only occurs in pages that have a `getServerSideProps` function, and only in production using a production build**, that this request is simply not sent. What ends up happening is the `auth` state stays at `null` which in the end leads to the page loading infinitely for the user.

**Why** is this happening, and **what** can I do to solve this bug?

**PS**: I will gladly provide any other info you need to answer this
**EDIT**: I know the request isn't sent because it doesn't appear in the console's network tab

Comment: How do you mount `<AuthProvider />`? I would not recommend to use async in `useEffect` callback.

Comment: Yes - my mistake for not following best practices. However removing the `async` from the useEffect function did not fix the problem at hand. The `<AuthProvider/>` is mounted inside of the `_app.js` page at the root level, with `<props.Component {...props.pageProps} />` as it's child

Answer (score 3):

It is not recommended to use async in `useEffect` callback like @Dimitri said. Try something like this.

```js
export const AuthContext = createContext();

export function AuthProvider({ children }) {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchAuthStatus() { 
      const { data: result } = await axiosApp.get("/auth-status"); // axiosApp = same thing as axios
      setAuth(result);
    }
    fetchAuthStatus();
  }, []);

  return !auth ? (
    <div className="pretend-this-is-a-progress-bar"></div>
  ) : (
    <AuthContext.Provider value={[auth, setAuth]}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Comment: While what you're saying is 100% correct, it is not the cause of the main problem at hand. Thanks a lot regardless!